# Excel formula for auto fill a date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date, multiple-instances

I would like to have cells F4-F23 auto fill today's date whenever data is entered into cells E4-E23. I then need to have cells I4-I23 auto fill with today's date whenever data is entered in cells H4-H23. Data entered in cells H4-H23 will be entered on different days then data entered in cells E4-E23. I found this code which works for the first part of my question, I need to know how to modify it to work on cells H and I.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim E As Range, F As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set E = Range("E:E")
    Set Inte = Intersect(E, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim E As Range, H As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set E = Range("E:E")
    Set H = Range("H:H")
    Set Inte = Intersect(E, Target)
    If Not Inte Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
        Next r
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    Set Inte = Intersect(H, Target)
    If Not Inte Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
        Next r
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Instead of exiting the sub when the intersection is nothing, check for the opposite of nothing and run the code on each intersection separately.

Note, I declared H as range and removed the unused declaration of F as range.